# WebRTC or Sip.js

Tags: webrtc, sip

I need to achieve peer to peer data transfer using webRTC.  I need to know which one is best to implement P2P. I saw webRTC and sip.js. But sip.js is really easier than webRTC. Which one is preferable?

Comment: WebRTC is a technology not a service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually WebRTC and sip.js serve different purposes. WebRTC is used to implement P2P connection to stream audio, video and data. sip.js is a JS implementation of SIP that can be used as a signaling protocol for WebRTC. I wrote an article in where you can find more details about WebRTC and different options for signaling protocol: https://beradrian.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/webrtc-saga/.